# How can I change svg size depending on my screen size in React Native?

Tags: css, reactjs, image, react-native, svg

I created adaptive layout in React Native, so everything I have to do is make my svg image scale with my screen size. How can I do that in React Native using react-native-svg?

Comment: the main idea is to have an svg element wirh a viewBox attribute but no width or height. This svg element will take all the width available.

Answer (score 1):

Using [react-native-responsive-screen](https://github.com/marudy/react-native-responsive-screen) you can use values depending on your screen size like as follow:

```
import {widthPercentageToDP as wp, heightPercentageToDP as hp} from 'react-native-responsive-screen';

class Login extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.textWrapper}>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: { flex: 1 },
  textWrapper: {
    height: hp('70%'), // 70% of height device screen
    width: wp('80%')   // 80% of width device screen
  }
});

export default Login;
```